# pine script - is there a way to get the close price of the current day to use it for past calculation on a close series[]?

Tags: pine-script

The goal is to use it as a constant throughout the entire price history of that asset.

I fear that it isn't possible because of the way the series[] data type works.
But i don't want to work around that by simulating the price with drawn lines or something.

Example on the ETHUSD chart, lets say it's the 3rd of November 2021:

```
closePriceOfBtcToday = ??  // = 62203.17
plot(close / closePriceOfBtcToday)
```

.. so that the ETH price is always divided by the 62203.17.

Comment: Remember, your script will be executed for each bar. So, do you want to use the close price of the last bar in the series, or literally the close price of today?

Comment: that's what i had in mind too :/
The close price of the last bar in the series.

And that might be the problem, because when i access the newest close price where barstate.islast, then I cant "back access" the older prices of the series which already have been plotted by that time

Comment: Just hardcode the price :)

Comment: that's my workaround for now, but then i have to update it everyday ._.

Comment: This looks like an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976952/previous-day-high-and-low-using-pine-script-v5