# Previous Day High and Low using Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am trying to convert a pinescript from v1 to v5.

v1

```
study(title="Previous Day High and Low", shorttitle="Previous Day High and Low", overlay=true)
D_High = security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
D_Low = security(tickerid, 'D', low[1]) 
D_Close =  security(tickerid, 'D', close[1]) 
D_Open =  security(tickerid, 'D', open[1]) 

plot(isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High",style=line, color=blue,linewidth=1) 
plot(isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low",style=line, color=blue,linewidth=1)
```

Output:
[image]

v1 is working fine.

I am trying to convert v5

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day High and Low New", shorttitle="Previous Day High and Low New", overlay=true)

D_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
D_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1]) 

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low", color=color.red,linewidth=2)
```

Output:
[image]

But its showing wrong. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pine v1-v2's `security()` function is using the lookahead parameter by default, which could be modified in v3-v5 with the `lookahead=` argument. To match the result declare the `barmerge.lookahead_on`:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day High and Low New", shorttitle="Previous Day High and Low New", overlay=true)

D_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 
D_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low", color=color.red,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='PDHL', shorttitle='PDHL', overlay=true)

// Get OHLC Data
i_timeframe ='D'
i_past = 1
[high_price, low_price]  = request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe=i_timeframe, expression=[high[i_past], low[i_past]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Hide Historical Plots
i_showlast = false
htf_islast = i_showlast ? request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe=i_timeframe, expression=barstate.islast, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : true

// Plot
high_break = high_price == high_price[1]
low_break = low_price == low_price[1]

plot(series=htf_islast and high_break ? high_price : na, title='High', color=#FF00ff, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_steplinebr, offset=-1)
plot(series=htf_islast and low_break ? low_price : na, title='Low', color=#00FFFF, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_steplinebr, offset=-1)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The logic was wrong because it was plotting the 2 days back on a new day.
Check out this version:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Previous Day High and Low New", shorttitle="Previous Day High and Low New", overlay=true)

D_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high) 
D_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low) 

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low", color=color.red,linewidth=2)
```